# Calculating character values in Java given an initial character and an offset

Tags: java, math, unicode, char, character

I want to generate single character strings to use as default labels -- think of column labels in a spreadsheet application. In my particular case, I simply need to draw from the set of Strings in ["A".."Z"], but the solutions I am trying could apply to lowercase Latin1 letter, numerals, characters from the Greek alphabet, etc.

A common solution in Java is something like:

```
static final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

static public char getLabel( int index )
{
    return alphabet.charAt( index );
}
```

It is reasonably efficient and a run-time error will result if `index` is not in [0..25], but it is typical Java in that it is verbose and requires even more code to verify it works correctly -- forgot the 'U' or is it transposed with 'V', etc...

So instead, I looked into the`Character` class to see if it provided methods for retrieving an ordinal value -- or Unicode index or numeric value -- which could be returned for a starting letter such a `'A'` in a Unicode block and category which could then be added to an integer producing a result used to "look up" the character required using another method which would return a `char` given a valid integer value where "valid" is dependent on the Unicode encoding. Sure enough, there are methods to do just that and quite a bit more. In fact there seem to be several methods which do the same thing, some which do the same with additional options such as specifying a radix for numeric values, and then a big time-sink in trying to grok the differences among "code points," "numeric values," "digits" (which are more convoluted than the method names would suggest), etc. In short, `Character` seems to offer useful methods for my simple requirement, but wrapped in a package which is far to complex to puzzle out for what I need to do.

Finally, there is the option of performing arithmetic on `char` primitives. Something like:

```
assert 'B' == 'A' + 1;
```

Well, almost. Java complicates things by converting all "integer" types smaller than an `int` to an `int` before calculating a result. Because `char` is considered an integer type -- and the only unsigned integer in the language -- it is subject to the same conversions even though a `Character` is not a `Number` and other issues crop up. Still, with a little bounds checking and casting when necessary, `'A' + x` appears to be pretty handy even though it presents issues as noted in the following example:

```
class CharTest
{
    static final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    static public char getLabel( int index )
    {
        return alphabet.charAt( index );
    }

    public static void main( String[] argv )
    {
        System.out.print( "getLabel( 5 ): " );
        System.out.println( getLabel( 5 ) );

        char a = 'A';
        char b = 'B';

        System.out.print( "a: " );
        System.out.println( a );
        System.out.print( "b: " );
        System.out.println( b );
        System.out.print( "++a: " );
        System.out.println( ++a );
        System.out.print( "--a: " );
        System.out.println( --a );
        System.out.print( "a++: " );
        System.out.println( a++ );
        System.out.print( "a--: " );
        System.out.println( a-- );
        System.out.print( "a += 1: " );
        System.out.println( a += 1 );
        System.out.print( "a -= 1: " );
        System.out.println( a -= 1 );
        System.out.print( "a += 5: " );
        System.out.println( a += 5 );
        System.out.print( "a -= 5: " );
        System.out.println( a -= 5 );

        System.out.print( "a + 1: " );
        System.out.println( a + 1 );
        System.out.print( "a - 1: " );
        System.out.println( a - 1 );

        System.out.print( "a + (char) 1: " );
        System.out.println( a + (char) 1 );
        System.out.print( "a - (char) 1: " );
        System.out.println( a - (char) 1 );

        System.out.print( "a + b: " );
        System.out.println( a + b );

        // The casts are just to show intent. I am aware Java will
        // simply add two ints and silently downcast to short.

        short z = (short) 1 + (short) 1;

        System.out.print( "short z = (short) 1 + (short) 1: " );
        System.out.println( z );

        // The same, only different...except the compiler
        // now requires the cast on the right-hand side
        // of the assignment to z or it fails with the
        // following error message:
        //
        //     error: possible loss of precision

        short x = 1;
        short y = 1;

        z = (short) ( x + y );

        System.out.print( "z = (short) ( x + y ): " );
        System.out.println( z );

        // Demonstrate that a is still 'A'. The following tests
        // produce results which indicate it is NUL ('\0') or
        // something even stranger...

        System.out.print( "a: " );
        System.out.println( a );

        // The following will not compile without the explicit
        // casts on the right-hand side of the assignments.
        // This results from converting a, b, and 5 to ints
        // before adding them which produces an int. The error
        // reported by the compiler is:
        //
        //     error: possible loss of precision

        char c = (char) ( a + 5 );

        System.out.print( "char c = (char) ( a + 5 ): " );
        System.out.println( c );

        char d = (char) ( a + b - a );

        System.out.print( "char d = (char) ( a + b - a ): " );
        System.out.println( d );
    }
}
```

The example code produces:

```
getLabel( 5 ): F
a: A
b: B
++a: B
--a: A
a++: A
a--: B
a += 1: B
a -= 1: A
a += 5: F
a -= 5: A
a + 1: 66
a - 1: 64
a + (char) 1: 66
a - (char) 1: 64
a + b: 131
short z = (short) 1 + (short) 1: 2
z = (short) ( x + y ): 2
a: A
char c = (char) ( a + 5 ): F
char d = (char) ( a + b - a ): B
```

Note that expressions involving `char`s which use binary operators require explicit casts while expressions using only unary, value updating operators do not.

Is there any reason to not use `char` arithmetic to solve my current, fairly trivial problem  involving the look up of characters known to be ordered within a specific block in Unicode? Or, should I use an indexed look up into a string constant, methods provided by the `Character` class, or another far more simple class I have overlooked in the JDK?

Comment: Why not just use `.charAt(index % 26)`?

Comment: `.charAt(index % 26)` is good, but I assume you mean something like: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".charAt(index % 26)`, right? Wrap around as a result of applying the `%` does not quite work for my current requirement, but could in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you haven't overlooked anything.  I think you have covered all of the sensible approaches for your particular use-case.

The choice boils down to:

- whether you want / need to validate the `index` argument, and
- whether you want (at some point) to be able to generalize this functionality; i.e. to deal with a larger *non-contiguous* range of characters.

In your position, I'd just choose the easier approach, wrap the functionality as a helper method, and move onto a more important issue.  (Making this a helper method simplifies things if you need to revisit your decision.)

---

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with your 50-or-so line test program, or why you are showing it to us.  It just seems to show Java arithmetic operators behaving normally :-)

---

FWIW, I think that the reason you won't find any clever methods for doing this kind of stuff in the `Character` class, etc, is that they are unnecessary.  Indexing a String (or a `char[]`) or arithmetic using the standard operators cover all of the typical use-cases.

Comment: The test program seems clearer now, but it was built up while trying to figure out which operators worked on `char` and how. In the end, the behavior is essentially the same as `short` or `byte`, but the details leading to the code explosion were not clear while working through IDE complaints, compiler errors, code fragments on the Internet, and the fact the Java 7 compiler "understands" `short z = 1 + 1` without the need for a cast (no doubt because constant folding happens before compiling the assignment), but not `short a = 1; short b = 1; short c = a + b;` unless a cast is applied.

Comment: Years ago, writing C code manipulating US-ASCII characters, the basic arithmetic operators where obvious and commonly used. Most other languages I have used over the years have provided something like `int ord(char)` and `char tochar(int)` rather that arithmetic on a `char` type. With Unicode and the many "unused" blocks within it, I was looking for something a little more "encapsulated." `Character` essentially provides that wrapped in a Rube Goldberg-esque package. In any case, I have finally worked out enough of the `char` arithmetic details to use it correctly for this application.

Comment: You seem to be a Java beginner.  Arithmetic with `byte`, `short` and `char` is a bit non-intuitive, but it all obeys a simple rule.  That is, the arithmetic operators always produce either an `int` or a `long`.  The operation-and-becomes operators then do a type cast implicitly, but for the rest you need to do the cast explicitly ... if you want the result to be interpreted as a `byte`, `short` or `char`.  This is not an artefact of some Java compiler or some platform.  It is a fundamental part of the language, specified in the JLS.  All conformant Java implementations behave that way.

Comment: Not a beginner, but I never bother with byte or short simply because Java never operates on them except to convert them. As a result, they are really only worth considering when allocating large arrays to hold small values. `char` is the same, of course. But Java does not consider `Character` a `Number` while `char` can be used as a small, but unsigned `int`. With often pointless inconsistencies, a very verbose syntax, the asymmetric OOP delusion that an arithmetic binary operator is a method of one number which takes another number as an argument, and the heavy reliance on conventions over...

Comment: ...language (Java beans and Java bean-like objects, anyone?), and cross-platform portability provided by an explicitly 32-bit virtual machine, Java is harder to work with than it needs to be when a programmer wanders off into an infrequently visited part of the field.

Comment: If you don't like Java, feel free to find a better language.  You are free to have your opinions, but complaining about Java here is not helping anyone.  I'm not going to indulge you by debating your points.

Comment: True about the complaints. I have them, but that is not where this began. In any case, thank you for your answer. Simple `char` arithmetic addresses my current need and indexing into a `String` or `char[]` will do the trick when I need to handle disjoint character ranges. I appreciate your time and attention.